# Bytecode incompatibility - java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class

Tags: java, runtime-error

I get this error when the `Jboss EAP 6.2.3` loads one of my application classes.

While I do understand the background of what this error means, I'm not sure if I'm interpreting the `"Implementing class"` part correctly. Debugging the `EAP` code, I was able to find the class that fails during the native `define` call. Let's assume the class name is `ClassX`.

```
[org.jboss.modules] (muxRequestListener-10) Failed to define class com.company.ClassX 
in Module "deployment.earDeployment.myApp.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:361) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
```

Does it simply mean that the class: `ClassX` thinks it's implementing an interface say, `InterfaceY`, but with a recent binary change, `InterfaceY` has now become a `Class` being an `Interface` previously?

Could it even result from loading any other class that the `ClassX` depends on (I hope not!) in the process of defining `ClassX`, because this should really help me pinpoint the error, but doesn't seem to?

Or is there a chance that this could be due to one of the various other causes of the error too and it simply manifests itself as `"Implementing class"` (I hope not again)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find out that the error meant exactly what it said!

It was in fact another type with the same package structure getting loaded (as opposed to a different version of the library being in use), but it's just that the culprit type was a `Class` as opposed to the intended type which was an `Interface`!